# What is the cause of the two different values?

Tags: java, state, transition, state-machine

I am trying to make an autonomous State machine. Below is pretty much the code I have. What it does is turn the state into ROBBINGBANK and then check values for changes and if it needs to change state. In every state it adds to a value or detracts. But when I test it, it does not give an error. But it makes a copy of the wealth value; What I mean is that the one in changeState has a different value than the one in robberStats. So that's why it always stays in the same state. Now I know the problem but not the solution. Can anybody help?

```
State st = State.ROBBINGBANK;
    public enum State {

        ROBBINGBANK,
        HAVINGGOODTIME,
        FLEEING,
        LAYINGLOW,
        CAUGHT
    }

    public void changeState() throws InterruptedException {
        BankRobber br = new BankRobber();
        while (st != State.CAUGHT) {
            if (st == State.ROBBINGBANK) {
                // got rich
                if (wealth >= 5000 && strength > 0) {
                    st = State.HAVINGGOODTIME;
                } // got tired
                else if (strength <= 0) {
                    st = State.LAYINGLOW;
                } // spotted cop
                else if (distanceToCop <= 20 && strength > 0) {
                    st = State.FLEEING;
                }
            } else if (st == State.HAVINGGOODTIME) {
                // got poor
                if (wealth <= 500 && strength > 0) {
                    st = State.ROBBINGBANK;
                } // spotted cop
                else if (distanceToCop <= 20 && strength > 0) {
                    st = State.FLEEING;
                } // got tired
                else if (strength <= 0) {
                    st = State.LAYINGLOW;
                }
            } else if (st == State.FLEEING) {
                // feel safe
                if (distanceToCop >= 50 && strength > 0) {
                    st = State.ROBBINGBANK;
                } // got tired
                if (strength <= 0) {
                    st = State.LAYINGLOW;
                }
            } else if (st == State.LAYINGLOW) {
                // feel safe
                if (distanceToCop >= 50 && strength > 0) {
                    st = State.ROBBINGBANK;
                }
            }
            else if(distanceToCop <= 0){
                st = State.CAUGHT;
            }
            br.robberStats();
            Thread.sleep(2000);
        }
    }

    public void robberStats() {
        if (st == State.ROBBINGBANK) {
            if (distanceToCop >= 20 && strength >= 8) {
                distanceToCop -= 20;
                strength -= 8;
            } else if (distanceToCop >= 20) {
                distanceToCop -= 20;
            } else if (strength >= 8) {
                strength -= 8;
            }
            wealth += 1000;
        } else if (st == State.HAVINGGOODTIME) {
            if (distanceToCop >= 10 && strength >= 2) {
                distanceToCop -= 10;
                strength -= 2;
            } else if (distanceToCop >= 10) {
                distanceToCop -= 10;
            } else if (strength >= 2) {
                strength -= 2;
            }
            wealth -= 150;
        } else if (st == State.FLEEING) {
            if (strength >= 4) {
                strength -= 4;
            }
            wealth -= 100;
            distanceToCop += 10;
        } else if (st == State.LAYINGLOW) {
            strength += 10;
        }

        System.out.println("wealth: " + wealth);
        System.out.println("strength: " + strength);
        System.out.println("distanceToCop: " + distanceToCop + "\n");
    }
```

Comment: I would step through your code in your debugger to see why it is not doing what you expect.

Comment: why are you using if-ladders to switch on an enum in robberStats()?  And what is the initial state (wealth, strength, and distanceToCop)?

Comment: Reduce your states to 2 and make the state transitions as simple as possible, get it working, then build up from there adding a bit of complexity at a time. Simple code is far easier to debug. The problem code will be easier to identify if the amount of code being added each time is small.

Comment: @Judge Mental that's because it first worked with String input to change states. And I did that with switches. But to do this I went to if-else. the initial states are: 0, 100, 200

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't answer your main question, but you said you appreciated constructive criticism... :)

I'd recommend you use the [State Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State_pattern) with an object for each state, rather than a single object that changes state. This will divide your logic into bite-sized pieces that will be easier to read.

I would advise not using an enum for the State, as it will make it harder for you to reliably alter / add states at a later date and make the code less flexible. However, if you define an interface for the state transitions, you could make the State implement that interface and then move the logic onto the State enum. That would be OK, because you leave it open to add new implementations of the interface without being forced to add them to the enum.

I'd also recommend writing automated tests one-by-one before you write the code that makes them pass. That way, you won't reach a point where your code doesn't work. It will work at every step of the way and the tests will protect you if you make design changes.

---

UPDATE:

@TheTerribleSwiftTomato

Using enums doesn't preclude compartmentalizing the state transition logic. Quite the opposite. It can provide a sensible place for that logic to go, i.e. put the logic that depends on state in the state objects themselves (the State Pattern). The problem with enums is they tend to fall foul of the [open/closed principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open/closed_principle).

In many cases, it doesn't matter; the set of states are very stable and/or extra enums can be easily added. In the OP's case, the states (ROBBING_BANK, FLEEING, LAYING_LOW etc) seem to me to be quite likely to change (e.g. INTERROGATED, ON_BAIL, FACING_JURY, SKIPPING_BAIL). By using an interface we can get the best of both worlds - use enums, for convenience and readability, and also allow arbitrary extension.

@user3047395

It's hard to give exact advice as this isn't my code. I personally tend to avoid enums for this kind of thing because I prefer to construct my objects with their dependencies rather than pass them in via methods. However, to make an easy transition to the State pattern, you could start with an interface with a method that gets passed a BankRobber, so it can query the properties and return a new state or return itself.

Comment: If I make each state into an object, where would I check the things I am doing now? And how would the interface work?

Comment: 1. I don't see how the use of enums precludes from compartmentalizing the state transition logic. Care to elaborate? 2. You assume that the goal is to remain flexible at all costs, but that is not always the case (in fact, this kind of thinking often leads to system-in-system effect). Enums also provide benefits in this case, e.g. easy identification of states.

Comment: I've responded in the post.